# Websocket doesn't work on the server in docker, but it works locally

Tags: python, websocket, redis, fastapi, uvicorn

When I run Fastapi locally on `127.0.0.1` the websocket works, but when I run this project through docker on the server, websocket does not work.

**dependencies**:

- python = "3.11.*"
- clickhouse-sqlalchemy = "0.2.4"
- fastapi = {extras = ["uvicorn"], version = "0.96.0"}
- pydantic = {extras = ["dotenv"], version = "1.10.8"}
- redis = "4.5.5"
- uvicorn = "^0.22.0"
- jinja2 = "^3.1.2"
- python-multipart = "^0.0.6"
- humanize = "^4.6.0"
- fastapi-redis-cache = "^0.2.5"
- asyncpg = "^0.27.0"
- tqdm = "^4.65.0"
- httpx = "^0.24.1"
- pytest-asyncio = "^0.21.1"
- aiosqlite = "^0.19.0"
- websockets = "^11.0.3"
- celery = "^5.3.1"
- psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.6"
- asgiref = "^3.7.2"
- xxhash = "^3.3.0"

**router:**

```py
import time

from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Request, WebSocket, status
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

from app.settings.config import templates

router: APIRouter = APIRouter()

@router.websocket("/ws/progress")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            await websocket.send_json({"message": "test" })
            time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await websocket.close()
    finally:
        await websocket.close()
```

**main.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, status
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.middleware.gzip import GZipMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse, PlainTextResponse
from fastapi_redis_cache import FastApiRedisCache
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

from app.settings.config import project_settings, redis_settings
from app.views.main_router import api_router

origins = ["*"]

app = FastAPI(title=project_settings.app_title,
              description=project_settings.description)
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="app/static"), name="static")
app.include_router(api_router)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
app.add_middleware(GZipMiddleware, minimum_size=1000)

if project_settings.debug:

    async def catch_exceptions_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
        try:
            return await call_next(request)
        except Exception as e:
            return JSONResponse(
                {"detail": "Internal server error", "error_mssage": str(e)},
                status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            )

    app.middleware("http")(catch_exceptions_middleware)

    @app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
    async def http_exception_handler(request, exc):
        return PlainTextResponse(str(exc.detail), status_code=exc.status_code)

    @app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
    async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
        return PlainTextResponse(str(exc),
                                 status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

if redis_settings.use_cache:

    @app.on_event("startup")
    def startup():
        redis_cache = FastApiRedisCache()
        redis_cache.init(
            host_url=redis_settings.url,
            prefix="fastapi-cache",
            response_header="X-MyAPI-Cache",
            ignore_arg_types=[Request, Response],
        )
```

**connection:**

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/api/v1/status/ws/progress");
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
   var progress = JSON.parse(event.data);
   console.log(progress);
};
socket.onclose = function(event) {
   console.log("Clossed");
}
```

[Server connection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjtnZ.png)

[Locally connection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTpF3.png)